# Is there a way to ask Ansible to retrieve the inventory from 2 different projects?

Tags: google-compute-engine, ansible

I have two Google Cloud Platform projects, one for staging and one for production. I would like the dynamic inventory system to retrieve the machines from both account (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_gce.html). How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Inventories are composable, so you can have as many dynamic inventory sources as you want. Just create a directory called `inventory` next to your playbooks, and create subdirs for each of your projects. Put a copy of the gce dynamic inventory script with its ini file in each of the project dirs, set it up the way you want, and just point ansible-playbook at the `inventory` directory with -i. Voila- you should see the hosts from both inventories.

You could also put two copies of the inventory scripts in the same directory (or symlinks) and rename them to be unique (ie, so they'd run twice), but in order to have a unique config for each, you'd have to hack the script to use a different config filename (or to dynamically use the name of the script itself, in the symlink case).

If you're using group_vars/host_vars dirs, it's best if you put them at the top level of the `inventory` directory (not down in the project subdirs). I haven't checked it under 2.0, but nested group_vars/host_vars didn't compose correctly in 1.9 last time I tried it.